# Want to change row background color of data-table

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

```
this.$('#route_data_tbl').dataTable({
        "bServerSide" : false,
        "sPaginationType" : "bootstrap",
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "110%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "oLanguage": { "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_  records per page" },
        "aaData":use_data 
});
```

hi this is my code for data-table which gives me output perfectly but i want to change the background colour of row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with CSS:

```
table.display tr.even.gradeA {
    background-color: red;
}

table.display tr.odd.gradeA {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```